# Loop to convert from raster to vector layer in PyQGIS

Tags: raster, pyqgis, vector

I'm trying to build a loop, in pyqgis, to convert a raster layer to vector, but I don´t know how to set the names in the loop.  The code is (see the second line of loop):

```
from osgeo import gdal
import os
from pathlib import Path
basepath = Path().home().joinpath("OneDrive","Documentos","DC")
rasterPath = basepath.joinpath("raster")
vectorPath = basepath.joinpath("guatemala.shp")
dir_recorte = rasterPath.joinpath("recortes")
dir_vectorizado = rasterPath.joinpath("vectorizado")

(...)

for lyr in dir_recorte.glob("*.tif"):
    output_path = dir_vectorizado.joinpath("prueba.GPKG")
    parameters = {
        'BAND': 1,
        'EIGHT_CONNECTEDNESS' : False,
        'EXTRA': '',
        'FIELD': 'DN',
        'INPUT': lyr.as_posix(),
        'OUTPUT': output_path.as_posix(),
    }
resultado = processing.run("gdal:polygonize", parameters)
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(QgsRasterLayer(resultado['OUTPUT'], output_path.stem, 'gdal'))
```

Any idea to solutions the problem?

---

Now, I have the code (below), but it returns an error ("Unavailable layer! Layer data source could not be found")

What am I doing wrong?

```
import os
in_folder = r"C:\Users\erick\OneDrive\Documentos\DC\raster\recortes"

#List all tif files in in_folder:
tif_list = []
for root, folder, files in os.walk(in_folder):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".tif"):
            #file is 'nh_76_8_density.tif'
            fullname = os.path.join(root, file)
            #fullname is the full path to the file:
            #'C:\\GIS\\data\\Hojddata_grid_50_plus\\2021\\nh_25_Norrbottens_lan_Sweref_99_TM_geotiff\\nh_76_8_density.tif'
            tif_list.append(fullname)
            
out_folder = r"C:\Users\erick\OneDrive\Documentos\DC\raster\vectorizado"
for tif in tif_list:
    print(tif)
    #C:\GIS\data\Hojddata_grid_50_plus\2021\nh_25_Norrbottens_lan_Sweref_99_TM_geotiff\nh_76_8_density.tif
    out_file = os.path.basename(tif) #Basename will give you just the file: 'nh_76_8_density.tif', from a full path
    out_vector = out_file.replace(".tif",".shp") 
    #'nh_76_8_density.shp'
    out_file = os.path.join(out_folder, out_vector) #Combine path and filename in a robust way
    
    #The processing goes here with tif as input and out_vector as output.
# Poligonizar
#for lyr in dir_recorte.glob("*.tif"):
#    output_path = dir_vectorizado.joinpath("Guatemala_{}".format(lyr.name))
    parameters = {
        'BAND': 1,
        'EIGHT_CONNECTEDNESS' : False,
        'EXTRA': '',
        'FIELD': 'DN',
        'INPUT': tif,
        'OUTPUT': out_vector,
    }
resultado = processing.run("gdal:polygonize", parameters)
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(QgsVectorLayer(resultado['OUTPUT'], output_path.stem, 'gdal'))
```

Comment: Bera, thanks! Input files have their own names, for example 201401.tif
.
.
.
201412.tif,
so I would like to name them, 201401.gpkg
.
.
.
201412.gpkg

Initially I had in the second row of the loop:
(...) output_path = trim_dir.joinpath("Guatemala_{}".format(lyr.name))
The problem is that with this, the extension (.tif) of the input files appears.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is purely python.

You can use `os` module and string `.replace`:

```
import os
in_folder = r"C:\GIS\data\Hojddata_grid_50_plus\2021\nh_25_Norrbottens_lan_Sweref_99_TM_geotiff"

#List all tif files in in_folder:
tif_list = []
for root, folder, files in os.walk(in_folder):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".tif"):
            #file is 'nh_76_8_density.tif'
            fullname = os.path.join(root, file)
            #fullname is the full path to the file:
            #'C:\\GIS\\data\\Hojddata_grid_50_plus\\2021\\nh_25_Norrbottens_lan_Sweref_99_TM_geotiff\\nh_76_8_density.tif'
            tif_list.append(fullname)
            
out_folder = r"C:\a_folder"
for tif in tif_list:
    print(tif)
    #C:\GIS\data\Hojddata_grid_50_plus\2021\nh_25_Norrbottens_lan_Sweref_99_TM_geotiff\nh_76_8_density.tif
    out_file = os.path.basename(tif) #Basename will give you just the file: 'nh_76_8_density.tif', from a full path
    
    out_vector = out_file.replace(".tif",".shp") 
    #'nh_76_8_density.shp'
    out_file = os.path.join(out_folder, out_vector) #Combine path and filename in a robust way
    
    #The processing goes here with tif as input and out_vector as output.
```